# What was wrong with using White Truffle Oil?

Tags: sauce, oil

On the show "Chopped", a contestant was running out of time to finish his entrée (using the mystery ingredients: gingersnaps, sweet potatoes, farina and turbot), and his dish did not have a sauce, so without any time to make one, the chef got a bottle of white truffle oil and dribbled a little amount on the plate.

The judges were horrified and screamed out "Noooo!" when he did this.

He got chopped.

What was so wrong with what he did with the white truffle oil?

Comment: What was the dish?

Comment: @Yamikuronue Don't remember the specific dish, but I added the mystery ingredients to the post.

Comment: Short answer: it's a not-so-great fashion trend going out of style, see http://www.seriouseats.com/2011/04/rant-enough-with-the-truffle-oil-already.html.

Comment: @rumtscho Funny then, if it's so frowned upon, that the kitchen show would have the bottle available in their pantry.

Comment: @Rum So the real answer is, the contestant was a fashion victim arrested by the fashion police?

Comment: @mfg Yes. A perfectly normal occurrence on Reality TV. And, LarsTech, I don't see a contradiction here. My father has more than one pair of bellbottoms in his wardrobe, I've just never seen him wearing them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It most likely contained artificial truffle flavoring (a synthetic agent such as 2,4-dithiapentane), and the judges were purists. Little to no real truffle flavor is used in truffle oils.

Answer (score 3):

A similar thing happened during the audition phase of season 2 of Master Chef.  The contestant gave a little drop of the White Truffle oil on her dish and the judges flipped.  Their explanation was that it contains no real truffle (as cptloop states) and further that the flavor is so over-powering, it masks all other flavors in the dish.